# Client Error at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPFaultBuilder.createFault(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:222)

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis

This is my first time with soap web services. I am trying to access this wsdl
https://servis.turkiye.gov.tr/services/g2g/kdgm/test/uetds?wsdl. I generated all the files with eclipse ws client tool. I am trying to access its methods. I know that service needs authentication. But I couldn't manage to do it properly. This is what I have tried so far.

```
UdhbUetdsService_ServiceLocator locator = new UdhbUetdsService_ServiceLocator();
        UdhbUetdsService_PortType portType = locator.getUdhbUetdsServicePort();
        UetdsYtsUser user = new UetdsYtsUser();
        user.setKullaniciAdi("999999");
        user.setSifre("999999testtest");
        System.out.println(portType.seferAktif(user, 1L, "test"));
```

Comment: Did you solved this problem? I'm on same job like you: Uetds

Comment: Check my answer @NuriAkman

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm trying to this job with PHP soapClient. But until now, there is no solution. PHP curl is working fine now. But, I prefer PHP soap (not nuSoap!)  solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it I have generated files with wsimport instead of eclipse client generator. Than the final code is this.

```
        UdhbUetdsService_Service service = new UdhbUetdsService_Service();
        UdhbUetdsService port = service.getUdhbUetdsServicePort();

        BindingProvider bp = (BindingProvider) port;
        Map<String, Object> map = bp.getRequestContext();
        map.put(BindingProvider.USERNAME_PROPERTY, "user");
        map.put(BindingProvider.PASSWORD_PROPERTY, "password");

        System.out.println(port.servisTest("Hello"));
```